# Why Jetty Not Start After Mvn Install

Tags: maven, plugins, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I use follow config pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.6.14.v20131031</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then I use `mvn clean install`, All build success, But the jetty not start not run.

Comment: Try mvn jetty:start instead.

Comment: `jetty:start` is OK,But I will use start after mvn clean install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the error.My config is error.
Use this is OK!

```
<build>  
        <plugins> 
            <plugin>  
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>  
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
                <version>8.1.0.v20120127</version>  
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>  
                        <contextPath>/mideaAdmin</contextPath>  
                    </webApp>  
                    <connectors>  
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">  
                            <port>9999</port>  
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>  
                        </connector>  
                    </connectors>  
                    <stopPort>8191</stopPort>  
                    <stopKey>ts</stopKey>  
                </configuration> 
                <executions>  
                    <execution>  
                        <id>start-jetty</id>  
                        <phase>install</phase>  
                        <goals>  
                            <goal>run</goal>  
                        </goals>  
                    </execution>  
                </executions>  
            </plugin>  
        </plugins>  
        <finalName>mideaAdmin</finalName>  
    </build>
```